# Windows Form based application layout/template

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

I am very new to Windows form based application. I have Visual studio 2012 and want to create a windows application.

This question might be asked before but I was not able to find any clear answer, so I decided to post the question here..

I want to know that if there is a way to create a master form (or a kind of template) for my application having common controls and rest of the forms can inherit that, likewise we do in web-applications.

I found somewhere that instead of going with Windows Forms application, I should go with WPF application, if that is the case can somebody point me to a good article where I can find some info about it....

Comment: Possible duplicate of [winform application master form](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17803169/winform-application-master-form). WPF - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5358733/is-there-a-concept-of-a-master-page-like-in-asp-net-for-wpf.

Answer (score 3):

I really advise you to work with WPF, windows forms is dead since years. WPF is very flexible and you can do far more things than windows forms.

Here is how to implement Master-Page like behavior using WPF: [Link](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/23069/WPF-Master-Pages).

Here are some WPF tutorial to start your journey:

http://www.wpftutorial.net/

http://www.tutorialspoint.com/wpf/

Learning **WPF** and **XAML** is great as it is very similar to most new technologies like **Android (layouts)**, **Xamarin (Forms)**, etc... So it is good technology to learn.